# Experience with VPN as SAAS?

Tags: vpn, saas

Has anyone experience with VPN running as SAAS? Means I dont run any hardware or local software, I dont need VPN experts (admins). A service where I can configure the network data per webclient. 
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You're *looking* for VPN as SAAS?

Check out LogMeIn's [Hamachi](https://secure.logmein.com/products/hamachi2/) service. Seems like it is exactly what you're after.

> LogMeIn Hamachi² is a hosted VPN
>   service that securely connects devices
>   and networks, extending LAN-like
>   network connectivity to mobile users,
>   distributed teams and business
>   applications. You can easily create
>   secure virtual networks on demand,
>   across public and private networks.

Answer (score 0):

Embedded into the AWS ecosystem, VPC is one solution (if you run an EC2 server and want to link it with your local infrastructure)